# 'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, gradle, apk

I'm having trouble when building an app to test my react-native app. I've looked up solutions on the internet but to no avail as I have the correct directory open.

```
C:\Users\Abdul\Desktop\release-5\Frontend\android\app>gradlew assembleDebug
'gradlew' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image]

Comment: Have you installed android studio (properly)?

Answer (score 1):

I expect that your path does not include the current directory.

Are you using cygwin or the built-ins?

You probably have to do something like:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

Answer (score 0):

As i can see you are executing `gradlew assembleDebug` in this directory `C:\Users\Abdul\Desktop\release-5\Frontend\android\app` but rather you should execute it from :

`C:\Users\Abdul\Desktop\release-5\Frontend\android`  directory, and . i hope it will work , feel free for doubts